# Firebase query documents by popularity(trending) crashes. Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Hi I'm trying to fetch some posts by their popularity, I need them to be posts from this month and to be ordered by the number of saved.

```
  func fetch() {
    let query = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").whereField("timestamp", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Date().ThisMonth).order(by: "Likes", descending: true)
        
        query.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if error != nil {
               print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
               return
            }
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            let data = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) })
            self.posts.append(contentsOf: data) 
        }
    }
```

But when I run the code I get the following:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid query. You have a where filter with an inequality (notEqual, lessThan, lessThanOrEqual, greaterThan, or greaterThanOrEqual) on field 'timestamp' and so you must also use 'timestamp' as your first queryOrderedBy field, but your first queryOrderedBy is currently on field 'Likes 'instead.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I already tried to do it this way but it still won't let me:

```
func fetch() {
    let query = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").order(by: "timestamp", descending: true).whereField("timestamp", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Date().ThisMonth).order(by: "Likes", descending: true)
    query.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                return
            }
        
        guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
        let data = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) })
        self.posts.append(contentsOf: data)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to order the posts in this way? What I want is to order them by popularity but only the posts of this month, not all the posts

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to have Firestore put your data in a specific order?  Is that something that you cannot do with posts?

Comment: What I am trying to do is sort a collection containing posts, each post contains a "Likes" number and a timestamp of a post date. What I want is to get the most recent posts and sort them by "Likes".

Comment: You are not allowed to sort and filter a field at the same time in Firestore.

Comment: Yes, firebase does allow you to filter the documents but for some reason it won't let me filter them when using "isGreaterThanOrEqualTo" and orderby("likes").

Comment: Ignore @ user17784435 comment as it's not accurate. Of course you can use .whereField and .order at the same time. (filter and sort) it's right in the documentation [Order and limit data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data).  You're first code example will definitely throw that error. Per the docs - *If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field* -. You're second query looks good to me. However, can you verify the second sort field is *Likes* not *likes* (lowercase)

Comment: @Jay Hi, thanks,I had already tried that way but the problem is that the documents are ordered by "timestamp" and not by "likes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error says that you have wrong field name `isGraterThenOrEqualTo:` it should be `greaterThanOrEqual:` and bad order of `.order()` method. Try bellow example.

**Get all doc created in this month**

```js
let query = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
   .whereField("timestamp", greaterThanOrEqual: Date().ThisMonth)
```

Then you must sort documents on client side by likes. It is becouse if you have `whereField("timestamp", greaterThanOrEqual: Date().ThisMonth)` with a range you have to first order by this field. And after that if you order with another field it only will work on items where `timestamp` is exacly same in both docs and will impact only those two docs.

**This is way you can sort in JavaScript**

```js
   posts.sort((a,b) => b.likes - a.likes)
```

Comment: Hi, I had already tried this way but it orders the documents by "timestamp" and not by "likes".

Comment: @AlejandraHernandez Check now are it order correct. Just put by likes in front.

Comment: Give vote up and mark a bird on left of my answear to set my answear as correct.

Comment: @AlejandraHernandez This cannot work as-is. The documentation clearly states *If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field* see [Limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations). Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: @AlejandraHernandez The answer has been updated but the solution is not going to scale well. The answer suggests loading ALL of the data onto the client and then sorting. That will crash with a large dataset - and Firebase datasets grow naturally over time. Moreover. Also, if your posts document contains any reasonable amount of data the crashes will happen sooner than later, and the UI will also slow to a crawl and become unresponsive. You may want to consider denormalizing your data to keep the set small.

Comment: @Jay Yeah you are right but i dont think so he is working on big project. He is just learning to use firebase. If i were him and i would know i will don't have more than 2-3k doc results i would just use `limit()` to dowload them all and sort if only admins or editors wuld need that. If users i would need to change it.

Comment: @Jay Hi, Where am I going to use this filter, it will only obtain 10 documents from the entire database, can this generate failures?

Comment: And another thing, in my app I use indexes a lot like: .whereField("verified", isEqualTo: true) and .order(by:), I use these indexes with pagination so that only they obtain 15 in 15 documents. Can this cause problems?

Comment: Use allways `limit()` and `limitToLast()` same as `.order()` if you want to controll how many docs you get from database. Some of yours `.whereField()` might have 1k documents and you are not able to download them all at once.

Comment: To paginate you need only `limit()` together with `startAfter()` to read query result untill last document. And `limitToLast()` and `endBefore()` if you end up on end of result and need go back page bacword.

Comment: When I use .whereField().orderby() I use pagination to get 15 documents and then another 15. That's fine right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241178/discussion-between-mises-and-alejandra-hernandez).